# Matplotlib show multiple images with for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display multiple figure in Matplotlib. Here's my code:

```
for i in range(8): 
    a = sitk.ReadImage("000%d.IMA"%(i+1))
    ...

    plt.figure(i+1)
    plt.imshow(a_np,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

However, figure(1) to figure(7) will show during the process but only figure(8) stay in the end. How can I see all of the figures at the same time?
It confused me that my environment is Ipython notebook when I change the environment to spyder the result will be correct.

Answer (score 12):

If you want 8 different figures in 8 different windows, here is an example that will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.linspace(0,10)
y = np.sin(x)

for i in range(8):
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.figure(i+1)

plt.show()
```

This will plot 8 different windows with `x vs y` and **all the windows will stay "alive" until you close them.**

Make sure you call `plt.show()` outside the `for` loop